# Adding a Pause Button

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I have the following code to create the stopwatch functionality. The only thing I would like to have is to create the startandstop button be startandpause. But I have been wracking my brain ang the internet trying to find out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Stopwatch
    var stopwatch;
    var runningstate = 0; // 1 means the timecounter is running 0 means counter stopped
    var stoptime = 0;
    var lapcounter = 0;
    var currenttime;
    var lapdate = '';


function timecounter(starttime)
        {
        currentdate = new Date();
        stopwatch = document.getElementById('stopwatch');
        var timediff = currentdate.getTime() - starttime;
        if(runningstate == 0)
            {
            timediff = timediff + stoptime
            }
        if(runningstate == 1)
            {
            stopwatch.value = formattedtime(timediff);
            refresh = setTimeout('timecounter(' + starttime + ');',10);
            }
        else
            {
            window.clearTimeout(refresh);
            stoptime = timediff;
            }
        }


function marklapH()
             {
             if(runningstate == 1)
                   {
                   if(lapdate != '')
                       {
                        var lapold = lapdate.split(':');
                        var lapnow = stopwatch.value.split(':');
                        var lapcount = new Array();
                        var x = 0
        for(x; x < lapold.length; x++)
             {
         lapcount[x] = new Array();
         lapcount[x][0] = lapold[x]*1;
         lapcount[x][1] = lapnow[x]*1;
              }
         if(lapcount[1][1] < lapcount[1][0])
              {
            lapcount[1][1] += 60;
              lapcount[0][1] -= 1;
             }
          if(lapcount[2][1] < lapcount[2][0])
             {
             lapcount[2][1] += 10;
             lapcount[1][1] -= 1;
              }
         }
       lapdate = stopwatch.value;
       Hlapdetails.value += (++lapcounter) + '. ' + stopwatch.value + '\n';
        }
     }


function startandstop()
      {
      var startandstop = document.getElementById('startandstopbutton');
      var startdate = new Date();
      var starttime = startdate.getTime();
      if(runningstate==0)
    {
     startandstop.value = 'Stop';
     runningstate = 1;
     timecounter(starttime);
     }
 else
      {
      startandstop.value = 'Start';
      runningstate = 0;
      lapdate = '';
      }
   }


function resetstopwatch()
        {
      lapcounter = 0;
      stoptime = 0;
      lapdate = '';
      window.clearTimeout(refresh);
     if(runningstate == 1)
   {
   var resetdate = new Date();
   var resettime = resetdate.getTime();
   timecounter(resettime);
  }
else
  {
    stopwatch.value = "0:0:0";
  }
 }


function formattedtime(unformattedtime)
  { 
   var decisec = Math.floor(unformattedtime/100) + '';
   var second = Math.floor(unformattedtime/1000);
    var minute = Math.floor(unformattedtime/60000);
decisec = decisec.charAt(decisec.length - 1);
second = second - 60 * minute + '';
return minute + ':' + second + ':' + decisec;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="show"></div>
<input type="button" id="start" value="start" onclick="countup()" />
<input type="button" id="pause" value="pause" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var h = 0;
var m = 0;
var s = 0;
var ml = 0;

document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "0:0:0:0";
function countup() {

ml++;

if (ml > 99 ) {

    s++;
    ml = 0;
}
if (s >59) {
    s = 0;
    m++;
}

if (m >59) {
    m = 0;
    h++;
}

var t = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ":" + ml;

document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = t;


}

var timer;
$("#pause").click(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
 });
$("#start").click(function () {
    timer = setInterval(countup, 10)
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks good. However I would name the function countup() instead of countdown() since that is what it does ... :-)